# Why the 1st example gets different results than the following 2 in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$b = (2,3)

$myarray1 = @(,$b,$b)

$myarray1[0].length #this will be 1
$myarray1[1].length

$myarray2 = @(
,$b
,$b
)

$myarray2[0].length #this will be 2
$myarray[1].length

$myarray3 = @(,$b
,$b
)

$myarray3[0].length #this will be 2
$myarray3[1].length
```

**UPDATE**

I think on #powershell IRC we have worked it out, Here is another example that demonstrates the danger of breaking with the comma on the following line rather than the top line when listing multiple items in an array over multiple lines.

```
$b = (1..20)

$a = @( $b, $b ,$b,
        $b, $b ,$b)

for($i=0;$i -lt $a.length;$i++)
{
  $a[$i].length
}        
"--------"
$a = @( $b, $b ,$b
       ,$b, $b ,$b)

for($i=0;$i -lt $a.length;$i++)
{
  $a[$i].length
}
```

produces

```
20
20
20
20
20
20
--------
20
20
20
1
20
20
```

In fact rather that using nested arrays that may complicate it here is a simple array of integers

```
$c = @( 1 , 2 , 
        3 , 4 )
for($i=0;$i -lt $c.length;$i++)
{
  $c[$i].gettype()
}        
"---------"
$c = @( 1 , 2 
       , 3 , 4 )
for($i=0;$i -lt $c.length;$i++)
{
  $c[$i].gettype()
}
```

and the results

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------        
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
---------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array    
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

I'm curious how people will explain this. I think I understand it now, but would have trouble explaining it in a concise understandable fashion, though the above example goes somewhat towards that goal.

Comment: The only justification that I can think of is that it's a bug in the parser. It doesn't seem like it should behave that way.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain the first example, but not the second two. The unary comma operator (see http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/) creates an array with one member, so `,$b` creates an array containing (`$b`); `,$b,$b` creates an array containing (`,$b` and `$b`).

The second two examples, I believe, are creating an array with one-element containing `$b,$b`. Then the one-element array gets flattened, yielding just `$b,$b`.

If somebody can post a link definitively explaining the behavior of the second two examples, I'd *love* to see it!

Comment: so what do you think of the more recent examples i've added to the question?

Comment: @klumsy: You can delimit an array with either a newline *or* a comma. It would appear that when you use both commas and newlines in the same array it tries to DWIM and sometimes cause confusing results.

Comment: its not quite that.. unless there is a comma at the ends of the line, telling Powershell that whatever is on the next line must be part of the same statement it treats each line as a separate statement, evaluating them in isolation, then putting them into the "pipeline" before getting wrapped back into an array with @()

Comment: @klumsy: That's plausible, but I'm not sure it explains $myarray2 and $myarray3.

Comment: This is exactly what I was saying to @klumsy in IRC. And his comment above is correct. The multiline examples are treated as separate pipeline statements. The leading comma wraps the object in an array, which is then unwrapped by the pipeline (unless you wrap it in yet another array at the same time).

Comment: @gabe , as for $myarray2 and $myarray3 .. it just SEEMS to work like normal commas.. what i happening is the same as if you hadn't put ANY commas on those lines. what is happening each of those is getting evaluated as a separate statement on a separate line. each item is getting wrapped with , into it another array, but when that gets collected through the "pipeline" , it gets unwrapped it has no effect at all. Another way to do that is  $myarray3 = @(,$b;,$b)